# Trying to find all factors of a number using recursion, end up with a segmentation fault for large numbers

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, cygwin, factoring

Why is there a segmentation fault?
I want to find all the factors of a number and put them in a vector. I have another function that does the same exact thing except it uses a while loop. So I thought I would try recursion. "i" initially starts at 1 unless I put some other value in the main.cpp. The "cout i" line is just there so I can see where it fails.

```
void recurfact ( std::vector <int> & facts, int numb, int i ) 
{
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  if ( i  > numb )
    {
      return;
    }

  if ( numb % i == 0 )
    {
      facts.push_back(i);
      i = i + 1;
      recurfact ( facts, numb, i );
    }
  else
    {
      i = i + 1;
      recurfact ( facts, numb, i );
    }
}
```

So this works if I test it with numbers less than 42800 +/- 100. If I try any number larger than that it just stops. The debugger says there is a segmentation fault. If I comment out the push_back line it still crashes at that i value.

However if I start with i = 45000, I can test numbers from 45000 to 85000 without a problem. Higher than 85000 it crashes.

I like to know why this occurs.

Compiling with gcc in cygwin on windows 7.

Error message from gdb is:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x000007fefcec10d6 in WaitForSingleObjectEx ()
>     from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll

Comment: Isn't the default stack size about 8 MB on Windows for GCC?  I know for .Net it's 1 MB per thread.  Usually I switch to explicit recursion (maybe use `vector<>` as a stack) with iteration which moves storage to the heap.  Of course, there are some great algorithms out there if you just want to find primes.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Do you want to know why this is? Do you want to know what to do about it? Or what?

Comment: Just ran a test, your stack looks to be 8 MB since that's when things blow up.  I've no clue why it's reported as a segmentation fault instead of a stack overflow however.  You're using gcc or g++ I assume?  Maybe paste the complete error message?

Comment: You would do well to limit this to prime factors. And is there something wrong with a for-loop (apart from the order of magnitude speed increase and solving your problem as a side-effect)?

Comment: I just wanted to practice with recursion and try out new methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this document about segmentation fault on Unix type systems:

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt

> Under Unix-like systems, programs may throw a "Segmentation Fault"
>   error.  This can be due to stack overflow, especially from recursive 
>   function calls or huge data sets.  In our demo program "Pi" (see
>   "$(CORE_PATH)/progs/pi"), we compute Pi to any number of desired bits
>   or digits.  Here are some test results on when stack overflows will
>   occur on different platforms, using their default stack sizes.